# How to use blend tool in Illustrator to blend continuosly?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending

[image]

Here's what I did.

1. Draw several circles with gradients.
2. Use blend tool and click each circle in place.
3. Replace spine.

I've tried several times but failed to achieve the dynamic colors. Also, how do I replace spine to fit to the path?

Comment: Hi Ricky Han, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Could you possibly add some screenshots showing your attempts? I just created [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/03XKj.png) with gradient filled circles and the blend tool, so I'm not sure what you're getting stuck on. Also I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence "replace the spine to fit to the path"?

Comment: @Cai How do I draw multiple circles and color them with different gradients so it will be multicolor as in the picture? Also how do I apply the "Replace Spine" for several continuous circles? Basically 2 circles is possible but multiple circles?

Comment: Ah ok, I see your problem! You definitely won't be able to do the whole thing in one continuous blend, the blend tool doesn't work well over complex paths. I would do it in sections, not sure about the overlaps on the corners though. It may be a case of patching the sections manually.

Comment: I **know** that you are asking about techniques to do this in Illustrator. However, [I found it amusing to try and replicate your target illustration in Blender 3D](http://i.imgur.com/34xlzku.png?1), just in case you're interested in seeing what it would look like! (took me approx. 15 minutes). Looking forward to see if you get an answer for this somewhat complex result you're trying to achieve in Illustrator. Good luck!

Comment: Looks great! The color and shades are amazing.

Comment: @RickyHan Hi, just found an answer to your question, I think, with multiple circles, I'll post shortly as soon as I get a free moment!

Comment: Why does mine turn out as a series of circles when I try and blend it? With solid colors it works but when I try to blend circles that have a gradient it just makes another circle

Comment: Set specifed step and lots of steps. Please dont use answer fields for questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find it is helpful to blend the palette you want arbitrarily first until you are happy with the colour transitions. You can then apply this palette blend to your desired path. The blend tool will generate a dynamic colour range between each blended colour/gradient.

**Step One:**
Create circle shapes for blending, and choose a gradient palette for each one. Note that colours that are adjacent to each other on the colour wheel blend rather well.

**Step Two:**
Blend the first two circles with the blend tool. Don't worry if your colour transitions look warped, this is fixed later.

> The order you blend the shapes is very important, as this will decide
>   the apparent z-order of the colours to be blended together

[image]

**Step Three:**
Selecting the resulting blend group and the subsequent gradient circle, use the blend tool again. Repeat this until you have created your blended palette for your design.

**Step Four:**
With the pen tool, draw the path to which you want to apply your blended colours.

[image]

**Step Five:**
With this path selected and the blend object, go to Object>Blend>Replace Spine

**Note:**

> You can improve the way in which the colours transition by selecting
>   the circles along the blend with the direct selection tool, then
>   rotating each one to improve the direction of the colour transitions.
>
> Using the Direct Selection Tool and various path editing tools, you can continue to edit the path to which you applied your blend group.

[image]

If you want to reverse the order in which blended colours appear on top of one another, go to Object>Blend>Reverse Front to Back

Comment: Great! One more question: How do you move the cross bar of `e` to the back?

Comment: You could try duplicating the blend group, Object>Blend>Reverse front to back. The duplicated letters should occupy the same space as the original, only reversed z order. Then you could mask out the y and h from my example. Hope that helps! I can't test that right now! Let me now how you get on! It was a nice question btw, I had fun experimenting with it :)