# Blending colors in photoshop and illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color, gradient, blending

I am working on a print for my wall and I am trying to create something like this:

[image: Example]

<sup>[Source](https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/1400/2e11e728476451.55c200a22fbf2.jpg)</sup>

I have already created the letters in Illustrator and now I am adding the colors in Illustrator and then exporting everything to Photoshop and then using the liquify tool to blend the colors to create a similar effect. I also used the healing patch tool to blend in the hard edges.

Is that the right way of doing it? Or is there another way?

Comment: I have no idea... It would be better if you post the images of your work. In any case I would try to stay in vector format all the way, so look for the mesh tool.

Comment: Although I'm sure it's perfectly possible I'm sure a gradient mesh would be an absolute nightmare to manage with all those smudges and color mixing effects. It would be *much* easier in Photoshop

Comment: Please post your images onto GD:SE - I can't see them on the other site - they're blocked by our company firewall.

Answer (score 2):

In Photoshop you can do this using the Mixer Brush tool, I just wrote a tutorial with video for you that goes into more detail [Multicolored Lettering with Mixer Brush](http://www.ryanfromgdse.com/72/multicolored-lettering-photoshop-mixer-brush). The basics are:

If you want these exact colors then I'd drop the image into Photoshop and sample them onto a new layer like so:

[image]

You can then use the Mixer Brush tool to either freehand the lettering or stroke a path. To use the path you can design it in Photoshop or Illustrator but then bring it into Photoshop, set the Mixer Brush up first then switch over to Pen, right click and stroke. Just have to change the Stroke from Brush or Pencil which is what its probably on to the Mixer Brush. Then use additional colors, brushes, and masks to refine and enhance the look.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That certainly seems like a reasonable way to achieve that effect.

I would, as you said, create the shapes and colors in Illustrator. You can achieve a similar effect using Illustrator's blend function. A good example can be seen here:

- [How to use blend tool in Illustrator to blend continuosly?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70772/how-to-use-blend-tool-in-illustrator-to-blend-continuosly/71276#71276)

I would probably go as far as creating the drips and blobs in Illustrator too. The large blobs don't need to blend with the background exactly as you can blend those in Photoshop later.

After importing your artwork in to Photoshop you can use the the liquify tool and smudge tool to get the effects on the colors. Use the dodge and burn tools for shadows and highlights and possibly a white brush for extra highlights.

Basically do as you have been doing.