# What is this called?

Tags: illustration

Does anyone have any idea what this kind of illustration is called, if it can be created with Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop and how?[image]

Comment: [This question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/75347/2611) and my answer on it will be the same for this just different colors. Feel free to comment on my answer over there if you need more help.

Answer (score -3):

This is a virtual paint brush simulation drawing.

Yes, both Illustrator and Photoshop can do this.

How? A blend of brush strokes and masking will achieve this goal.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: on what should I elaborate?

Comment: Let me spare you the time, and the others some trouble. For each part you want to make (strokes, colouring, holes, pooling, shadows, drips) create separate questions.

Comment: To spare everyone the confusion. I'd just ask them all in one question.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You've already asked three questions, in this one. They don't take kindly to multiple questions in a question around here. And they have a particularly strong response to requests for technique and process paradigms and mechanics. [off-topic part deleted by moderator]

Comment: So sorry.

I have restructured the question into one here. Thanks
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107307/how-can-i-make-this