# How can I achieve this lettering style?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typography, lettering

[image]

I have tried almost everything and scratched my brains over it but still, I am not able to figure it out. Please help me to achieve this lettering.

Comment: 3D application....

Comment: I'm sure there's a duplicate somewhere, have you used our search tool?

Comment: related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73715/blending-colors-in-photoshop-and-illustrator

Comment: I tried using your search tool but I couldn't find the technique to the style. I also referred to the link you gave but I strongly believe that there is a difference between the two.