# 3D Acrylic Paint Stroke in Photoshop or C4D?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stroke, painting, cinema4d

[image]

How can I make this kind of 3D paint stroke? Is it photoshop or C4D. please guide me through the process.

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times. Return to your original question and see about editing it so it gets removed from being on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure, of course, but it *looks* to me like it was most likely produced in a 3D DCC tool, and yes C4D would work.

The three linear or curvilinear "brushstrokes" look like simple box modeled meshes, which were then distorted through a curve (mograph I'm sure) and each has a shader / texture applied which is the brush stroke, created in either PS or Illus, with an alpha channel for transparency to get the ragged rear end of each stroke. Each has a slight thickening at the forward edge, but other than that they are pseudo-2D folded to give the 3rd dimension.

The larger splatty mass looks sculpted, and there are many ways to approach that feel - what give all these elements the cohesion and the look is the paint stroke textures, and there's another Stack Exchange Graphic Design answer out there about that sort of thing:

[Blending colors in photoshop and illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73715/blending-colors-in-photoshop-and-illustrator)

It's also *quite* possible this was all done in Photoshop or similar, with brushes, and careful application of shadows and highlights to give the 3D feel.